# Copy filenames at source based on wildcard to be transferred to seperate folders in Sink using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I'm looking to configure an ADF job to transfer .txt files from the source container using the Copy function and transfer them to an ADLS Sink container in their respective folders.

For example:

Source Container A
Directory
-fileA-20240201.txt
-fileB-20240302.txt
-fileB-20230201.txt
-fileC-20230201.txt

Sink Container B
Directory
-Folder_A
-Folder_B
-Folder_C

transfer fileA* using wildcard and transfer those files to Folder_A.  transfer fileB* using wildcard and transfer those files to Folder_B.  transfer fileC* using wildcard and transfer those files to Folder_C.

Looking for help on config details setting up this ADF job.

Tried to use ForEach nested with a Switch Activity using Case Activity for each file name followed by copy activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you knew the number of target folders and list of target folders, then you can try the below approach.

**These are my sample input files:**

```
sourcecon
    folder
        fileA-20240201.txt
        fileA-20240311.txt
        fileB-20230201.txt
        fileB-20240302.txt
        fileC-20230201.txt
        fileC-20240310.txt
```

First create an array variable with letters `["A","B","C",..<till required folders>]`. Give this array to a For-Each activity.

Create source dataset and target datasets. In target dataset, create a string parameter `folder_name` and give that to the folder path of the dataset like below.

[image]

Inside for-loop, take a copy activity and give the created source and sink datasets. In the source, use the wild card path with this expression `file@{item()}*` like below.

[image]

In the sink, give the expression `Folder_@{item()}` to the dataset parameter.

[image]

Debug the pipeline and all required files will be copied to the respective folders like below.

**Target folders:**

[image]

**Files created in the target folder:**

[image]

**My pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@createArray('A','B','C')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "wildcardFolderPath": "folder",
                                        "wildcardFileName": {
                                            "value": "file@{item()}*",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sourcefiles",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "targetfiles",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "folder_name": {
                                            "value": "Folder_@{item()}",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2024-03-11T13:35:47Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh Govindula.  If it isnt much trouble and you still have the pipeline do you mind providing a JSON file for the pipeline.

Comment: I have added my pipeline JSON. Build your pipeline but make sure to edit the required changed as per your requirement.